# How to access Kafka streams windowed state store

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I have a topic contains ledger entries and I want to access the them based on time window. For example, give me all entries in the last hour. Or give me entries from 1 am to 2 am etc.

The following is the stream topology. It transforms the key/value and then groups by the key and then windowed in one hour. After windowing, there will be multiple records within that one hour and I want to access them all by specifying the from time and to time. There is no way to specify materialized view here. All examples I can find will further count/aggregate/reduce to a single record and then materialized it. Is there a way I can access the internal Windowed state store? Thanks.

```
builder.stream("topic").transform() ..., keyValueStoreBuilder.name()).groupByKey().windowedBy(TimeWindows.of(360000));
```

Comment: You can user Interactive Queries feature: https://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/developer-guide/interactive-queries.html

Comment: Matthias, Thanks for the answer. I am using Interactive Queries for a lot of applications and it is not an issue for me. The issue is to find an example that aggregate transactions into a list windowed in one hour and access it from another part of the application. I cannot find any working example on the Internet and Github.com.